# documentações e links sobre efeito hover

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

ola pessoal gostaria de saber se existe algum material ou documentação que me auxilie pois preciso criar um efeito `:hover` parecido com o desse site [aqui](http://bootexperts.com/html/sauget-ecommerce/sauget/index-2.html#)

OBS: o efeito `:hover` e da parte de e-commerce onde fica as fotos das roupas e aparece o botão de comprar

Comment: Isso chama **Creative CSS3**, vários site q tem animação muito bonito, veja esse http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CreativeCSS3AnimationMenus/index4.html e flw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copiei do site e falta icone, isso não carrega googleapis é direito autoriais, use FontAwesome (http://fontawesome.io) pode ajudar. flw

```html
<html>
<link href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CreativeCSS3AnimationMenus/css/style4.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CreativeCSS3AnimationMenus/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Terminal+Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<body>
  <ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon">F</span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Exceptional Service</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Personalized to your needs</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon">H</span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Creative Storytelling</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Advanced use of technology</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon">N</span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Infographical Education</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Understanding visually</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon">K</span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Sophisticated Team</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">Professionals in action</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon">L</span>
        <div class="ca-content">
          <h2 class="ca-main">Unconditional Support</h2>
          <h3 class="ca-sub">24/7 for you needs</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body></html>
```